# How to change the Row Number behavior in my T-SQL Query?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am using SQL Server 2014 and I have the following T-SQL query running against a table (tbl1).

Extract of tbl1:

```
emp_code     Name     Address   Company
---------------------------------------
100          Peter    London     ABC
125          Allan    Cambridge  DCE
125          Allan    Cambridge  DCE
115          John     Suffolk    ABC
115          John     Suffolk    XYZ
154          Mary     Highlands  ABC
154          Mary     Bristol    ABC
124          Mary     Chester    ABC
```

My T-SQL query stands as follows:

```
SELECT
    [ID],
    [Name],
    [Address],
    [Company],
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY [emp_code] ORDER BY [Address]) AS RowNumber
FROM
    [tbl1]
```

Output from above query:

```
emp_code         Name     Address   Company    RowNumber
--------------------------------------------------------
    100          Peter    London     ABC          1
    125          Allan    Cambridge  DCE          1
    125          Allan    Cambridge  DCE          2
    115          John     Suffolk    ABC          1
    115          John     Suffolk    XYZ          2
    154          Mary     Highlands  ABC          1
    154          Mary     Bristol    ABC          2 
    154          Mary     Chester    ABC          3
```

Output I'm after:

```
emp_code         Name     Address   Company    RowNumber
---------------------------------------------------------
    100          Peter    London     ABC          1
    125          Allan    Cambridge  DCE          1
    125          Allan    Cambridge  DCE          1
    115          John     Suffolk    ABC          1
    115          John     Suffolk    XYZ          1
    154          Mary     Highlands  ABC          1
    154          Mary     Bristol    ABC          2 
    154          Mary     Chester    ABC          3
```

I want my RowNumber (or change the column name if need be) to change based on the `[Address]` column for each `[emp_code]`. If the employee has the SAME address, it should have the same value (that is, 1). Else, it should give the values as in the case of employee "Mary" (above output).

I am assuming the `Row_Number()` function is not the right one to be used for what I'm after.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: The last row doesn't look correct.  Why does `emp_no = 124` have a "3"?

Comment: My bad! The ID should have been 154. Corrected.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you want `DENSE_RANK` here rather than `ROW_NUMBER()`:

```
SELECT [ID], [Name], [Address], [Company],
       DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY [emp_code] 
                          ORDER BY [Address]) AS DenseRank
FROM [tbl1];
```

[image: screen capture from demo link below]

### Demo